# Boostrap tooltip doesn't render after inserted comment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented a comment system on my web app where the comment is returned from the server as a JSON format if the record was saved correctly into the database.

Everything else seems to render properly except tooltip which holds links for editing and deleting the comment. After comment is been appended to a div, the tooltip isn't holding those links hidden.

I'm using CodeIgniter as a PHP framework, although this information may not be useful since it's an UI problem.

**Here's my PHP code for inserting the comment (../application/controllers/comments):**

```
public function add() {

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $event_id = $this->input->post('event_id');
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('event_comment', 'Kommentti', 'trim|xss_clean|required|htmlspecialchars');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === false) {

            $this->output->set_content_type('application_json');
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('st' => 0)));
            return false;
        } else {

            $data = array('event_id' => $event_id, 'user_id' => $user_id, 'comment' => $this->input->post('event_comment'));

            $comment = $this->comment_model->addComment($data);
        }

        if ($comment === true) {

           $this->load->model('comment_model');
                $new_comment = $this->comment_model->getNewestComment($event_id, $user_id);

                $this->output->set_content_type('application_json');
                $this->output->set_output(json_encode($new_comment));
                return true;
        } else {

            $this->output->set_content_type('application_json');
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('st' => 0)));
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's my AJAX (../public/js/ajax.js):**

```
$("#event_comment").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        var from = $('.form-comments');

        $.ajax({
            url: from.attr('action'),
            type: from.attr('method'),
            data: $(from).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                    // Piilotetaan "Luo tapahtuma" - painike ja korvataan se
                    // "spinner" - ikonilla
                    from.find(".form-comment-send").hide();
                    from.find("#spinner_comment").show();
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data) {

                        // RENDER MESSAGE HERE AND APPEND IT TO COMMENT BODY
                        renderCommentHTML( data[0] );

                    }

                }, complete: function() {
                    from.find("#spinner_comment").hide();
                    from.find(".form-comment-send").show();
                }
            });
        return false;
    }
});
```

**And finally the function for rendering the HTML (../public/js/functions.js)**

```
function renderCommentHTML(data) {

var comment = '';

comment += '<div class="event-comments-comment post-comments-comment media" id="'+ data.id +'">';

        // tooltip starts here                  
        comment += '<div href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="pull-right">';
        comment += '<i class="fa fa-chevron-down grey fa-1x no-pad"></i>';              
        comment += '<div class="tooltip-content">';
        comment += '<a role="button" class="btn-edit">Muokkaa</a>';           
        comment += '<form action="comments/delete" method="post">';
        comment += '<input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="'+ data.event_id +'">';
        comment += '<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="' + data.id +'">';
        comment += '<button type="submit" name="delete_comment">Poista</button>';
        comment += '</form>';
        comment += '</div>';
        comment += '</div>' 
        // Tooltip ends here                

        comment += '<a class="media-left" href="#">';
            if(data.is_fb_img == 0) {    
                comment += '<img class="comment-pic semi-round" src="'+url+'public/images/uploads/profiles/'+ data.profilepic +'">';
            } else {
                comment += '<img class="comment-pic semi-round" src="'+ url + data.profilepic +'">';
            }
        comment += '</a>';

        comment += '<div class="media-body wide">';
        comment += '<h5 class="media-heading">'+ data.name +'</h5>';
        comment += '<div class="edit_comment_area">';
        comment += '<div class="comment-container">';
        comment += '<form action="events/edit" method="post" class="edit-comment">';
        comment += '<input type="hidden" name="c_id" value="'+ data.id +'">';
        comment += '<div class="comment-text">'+data.comment+'</div>';
        comment += '</form>';
        comment += '</div>';
        comment += '</div>';

        comment += '<div class="comment-date">';
        comment += '<span data-livestamp="'+ new Date().toISOString() +'"></span>';
        comment += '</div>';        
        comment += '</div>';
        comment += '</div>';

        $('.comment-holder').append(comment);
}
```

Comment: Have you turned the tooltips on? As of the latest Bootstrap they aren't on by default.

Comment: Yes they are on.. If I don't post the comment with AJAX (redirect the page with php after inserting the comment) the tooltip is hiding those elements just fine.